# mysqldump not backingup to specified file

Tags: wamp, mysql

I have the following problem, I tried to back up a database using mysqldump command, and after I enter the corrent command on the terminal:

This is the command:

```
c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin>mysqldump -uroot -ptest store > store_bak.sql

/* here it jumps to the next line after pressing ENTER */

c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin>
```

I think I'm entering the correct commands on the right place, but the only thing that happens is that it jumps to the next line and no backup is made.
I also cannot find any file named as the backupname I specified (store.sql on this example)

does anybody knows what could be causing this?

ps: i'm using wamp, on windows 7, sql 5.5.24

Comment: Do you have the rights to write in this folder?

Answer (score -1):

you need spaces here -uroot -ptest

mysqldump -u root -p test -h localhost store > store_bak.sql

Comment: Wrong! Especially after -p a space is considered as "no password named, the next word must be the database name".

Comment: nope, i already find the "problem". first of all thanks for the reply Alex. You actually DON'T need spaces for those commands, try it out and you'll see they still work. The problem was Layer 8 ;). All the backups where been placed on mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin I thought they suppose to be on the data folder inside bin, but anyways, I quick search help me out, sorry for the problem. regards to you all.